# In C++, can I prevent derived class being instantiated by classes other than friends

Tags: c++, oop

In C++, if I have a abstract base class, is it possible to prevent its derived classes being instantiated by classes other than friends that the base class knows?

Comment: If this was C# I would suggest marking it as Internal so that only the "friend" classes would know the base. This would prevent creating inheritance outside the friend zone. If however you want to extend beyond that, but only construct from the friend zone, it is a much more complex issue.

Answer (score 7):

You can define constructors as private, just like any other function. For example:

```
class foo
{

friend foo *FooConstructor(void);

public:
  void Method();
  void Method2();

private:
  foo();
  foo(const &foo);
};

foo *FooConstructor(void) 
{ 
  return new foo(); 
}
```

This prevents a `foo` being created in any way, save with the `FooContructor` function.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways you can have a base-class internal

The first is to make the constructors private, like this:

```
struct Sub1;
struct Sub2;

struct Base
{
    virtual ~Base() = default;
private:
    Base() = default;
    Base(const Base&) = default;
    friend struct Sub1;
    friend struct Sub2;
};

struct Sub1 : protected Base {}; // ok, its a friend
struct Sub2 : protected Base {}; // ok, its a friend
struct Sub3 : protected Base {}; // compiler error
```

The second way is to declare the base-class in a anonymous namespace:

```
namespace {
    struct Base{};
}

struct Sub : Base {};
```

Now, all classes in the same translation unit can use `Base`,
but other classes wont know it exists.

This way is often less desirable, since derived classes can only
be used as incomplete types (forwarded)